# Avoid reload content on beginUpdates of UITableView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a cell with a textview and it has a `view more` button. When press this button the cell is expanding accordingly. I've called,

```
[self.parent.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.parent.tableView endUpdates];
```

These methods are calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I'm setting an initial height for the textview(height when text is shrink). When calling this with the beginUpdate the text view collapses automatically because text view is setting the initial height.

I've tried to remove the `beginUpdates` but it shows only a part of the text. Not the full text.

**in cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
 if (self.postTextView.text.length >= 100) {
    CGSize initialHeight = [self calculateHeightForString:(post.fullText.length > 100)?[post.fullText substringToIndex:100]:post.fullText];
    self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = initialHeight.height + 40;
} else {
    CGSize initialHeight = [self calculateHeightForString:post.fullText];
    self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = initialHeight.height + 40;
}
```

**Shrinking Text**

```
UITextView *textView = (UITextView*)((UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender).view;
OCPost *post = [self.parent._posts objectAtIndex:textView.tag];
NSMutableAttributedString *answerAttributed = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:post.fullText attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"SFUIText-Light" size:18.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]}];
self.postTextView.attributedText = answerAttributed;
self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = [self fullHeightOfString:self.postTextView.attributedText].height + 40;
[self.parent.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.parent.tableView endUpdates];
readMoreGesture.enabled = NO;
```

How may I fix this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Use constraints and auto-layout. Calling `beginUpdates` / `endUpdates` should *not* call `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, unless it changes the visible rows. That is, if you have 8 rows visible, and you "expand" row 2 - pushing rows 7 and 8 off the screen, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should not be called. If you then "shrink" row 2 - which brings rows 7 and 8 back into view, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be called - but only for rows 7 and 8.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the state of the cell in a separate variable.

Let's call it `var isExpanded: Bool = false`. When you tap show more, the state should be set to `true`, and you use that variable in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to determine the proper height for it.

Comment: Yeah. I've done it. But when it should be true and when it should be false?

Comment: When you tap on "Show More" set it to true then do the `beginUpdates` `endUpdates` methods.

Comment: Set it to false when you want the content to collapse and not show all.

Comment: OK. But I don't have a way to collapse. That's why I'm struggling here. :)

Comment: Oh well this is a UX issue then. Maybe there should be a "Show Less" button? I don't know.